# unload data to s3 with new line characters redshift

Tags: sql, database, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

i am trying to export table from redshift to s3 using unload command 
command :

```
unload ('SELECT * FROM table where id = 4') TO 's3://path/temp/table1'
 credentials 'aws_access_key_id="ahsvdgsfadhsagdffjh;aws_secret_access_key=ahgsdasdhgsahdgsahdgsahdgsahgsa' delimiter '|' NULL
AS
'\\N' escape;
```

one of the field in my table contains new line so the csv generated breaks into two lines

is there any way to replace new line to \n or to add a end of line character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be removing `escape`, and just try `ADDQUOTE` Option, it will produce correct CSV. As `""` will instruct your CSV reader to treat `\n` as verbiage rather than `newline`.

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT * FROM table where id = 4') 
TO 's3://path/temp/table1'
credentials aws_access_key_id="ahsvdgsfadhsagdffjh;
    aws_secret_access_key=ahgsdasdhgsahdgsahdgsahdgsahgsa' 
delimiter '|' 
NULL AS '\\N' ADDQUOTE;
```

Comment: tried ADDQUOTE already all the fields get wrapped in quotes but still creates new line

Comment: Yes, new line will remain, I don't think you want to remove it as all. correct? otherwise it will change your actual data. But when you open the CSV say using `MSExcel`, the cell data will be `visible properly`. `It will not appear as new record`.

Comment: actually i have to import it into mysql using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE for that purpose its not working

Comment: Infact that would be easier, as MySql import does support it, use `enclosed by "` Option like  `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '$file'  INTO TABLE $table  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES`